# Обтекание текста вокруг картинки в ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Можно ли сделать с помощью `ConstraintLayout` такое обтекание текста вокруг картинки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. текст в `TextView` должен находиться справа и снизу от `ImageView`, при этом картинка в `ImageView` должна занимать всю видимую (свободную) высоту экрана, ширина картинки при этом должна быть такой, чтобы картинка имела правильные пропорции, и экран должен прокручиваться (скроллиться).

У меня получается заставить `ImageView` быть равным по высоте контейнеру с сохранением пропорций, но текст при этом "уезжает" вправо:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/avatar"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/details"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/avatar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/avatar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И не получается сделать прокручивание, т.к. в случае, если я оборачиваю `ConstraintLayout` в `ScrollView`, `ImageView` начинает занимать и невидимую часть экрана:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        ...

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же обернуть `TextView` в `ScrollView`, размер картинки правильный, но прокручивается только текст справа, картинка остаётся на месте, а это не совсем то, что мне нужно - текст не обтекает картинку, а просто прокручивается справа от неё.

Или с помощью `ConstraintLayout` и `ScrollView` так сделать невозможно? C помощью каких контейнеров тогда лучше сделать такой макет?

Comment: уверенно могу сказать, что одной картинкой и одном TextView это  сделать нельзя. Я бы на вашем месте реализовал html страницу, т.к. с ее помощью это решить гораздо проще.

Comment: Одной картинкой и одним TextView это сделать нельзя. Говнокодить с помощью html страницы сильно не рекомендую.

Comment: @Suvitruf, а как тогда лучше это сделать?

Comment: @Ksenia я такое представляю возможным сделать, если создать свой компонент и там переопределять методы вроде `onMeasure` и т.п. Хотя, почему-то мне кажется, есть готовый компонент с таким поведением)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант предлагаю не готовый ответ, а направление. А именно, использовать два `textview`: один справа, один снизу. Определять наполнение текстом в первом и переносить остаток во второй. Ссылки по теме:

1. [определить переполнение `textview`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28616362/5330439)
2. [Разбивка текста](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837840/paginating-text-in-android/32096884#32096884)